# How to update soanr.properties of docker based installation

Tags: docker, ubuntu, sonarqube

I am pretty new to Docker. Now I want to run a docker version of Sonarqube and upate the property file (sonar.properties) inorder to point my databsae to mysql rather than the default H2.

I am able to run the image with default configuration and even performed a scan on it. While following the instructions in its official docker page ([Sonarqube docker documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/?tab=description)), I am not able to proceed further from the second point under the "First Installation" heading. Second point is as follows

```
Initialize SONARQUBE_HOME folder tree with --init. This will initialize the default configuration, copy embedded plugins, and prepare the data folder:

$ docker run --rm \
-v $SONARQUBE_HOME/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf \
-v $SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions \
-v $SONARQUBE_HOME/data:/opt/sonarqube/data \
sonarqube --init
```

which I believe will help me to have a custom configurations folder. Following error shows up while running this command.

> renju@renju-pc:~$ sudo docker run --rm -v
>   $SONARQUBE_HOME/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf -v
>   $SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions -v
>   $SONARQUBE_HOME/data:/opt/sonarqube/data sonarqube --init tail: cannot
>   open './logs/es.log' for reading: No such file or directory
>   01:33:11.950 [main] WARN
>   org.sonar.application.config.AppSettingsLoaderImpl - Configuration
>   file not found: /opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Command-line
>   argument must start with -D, for example -Dsonar.jdbc.username=sonar.
>   Got: --init   at
>   org.sonar.application.config.CommandLineParser.argumentsToProperties(CommandLineParser.java:56)
>     at
>   org.sonar.application.config.CommandLineParser.parseArguments(CommandLineParser.java:37)
>     at
>   org.sonar.application.config.AppSettingsLoaderImpl.load(AppSettingsLoaderImpl.java:66)
>     at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:51)     at
>   org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:98)

My asumption is that it is because of the unavailability of the folder "opt/sonarqube/conf".

Why is that folder missing? As per doc,

```
Use bind-mounted folders
The images contain the SonarQube installation at /opt/sonarqube. You need to use bind-mounted folders to override selected files or directories :

/opt/sonarqube/conf: configuration files, such as sonar.properties
/opt/sonarqube/data: data files, such as the embedded H2 database and Elasticsearch indexes
/opt/sonarqube/logs: contains SonarQube logs about access, web process, CE process, Elasticsearch logs
/opt/sonarqube/extensions: plugins, such as language analyzers
```

Am I missing any intermediate steps here?

I work on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Are you running on host also? i think overiding conf is engouhg `docker run --rm -v $PWD/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf `

Answer (score 4):

You are not missing anything. 
Current documentation in the Docker Hub is for the Sonarqube 8. They are working on releasing documentation for the Sonarqube7.

Please check the below link: https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/340#issuecomment-553397995

Please follow the below steps.

1. Create volumes sonarqube_conf, sonarqube_data, sonarqube_logs, and sonarqube_extensions and start the image with the following command. This will populate all the volumes (copying default plugins, create the Elasticsearch data folder, create the sonar.properties configuration file). Watch the logs, and, once the container is properly started, you can force-exit (ctrl+c) and proceed to the next step.

   $ docker run --rm \
   -p 9000:9000 \
   -v sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf \
   -v sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions \
   -v sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs \
   -v sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data \
   %%IMAGE%%
2. Run the image with your JDBC username and password

   $ docker run -d --name sonarqube \
   -p 9000:9000 \
   -e sonar.jdbc.username=sonar \
   -e sonar.jdbc.password=sonar \
   -v sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf \
   -v sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions \
   -v sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs \
   -v sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data \
   %%IMAGE%%